# Hypothesis Testing - Median Test for linear regression model given standard error and co-efficient

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science-model, data-analysis, hypothesis-testing

I need help approaching this particular problem on hypothesis testing.

A researcher believes that a diet high in raw cornstarch would increase the median blood glucose levels by 20. The diet can either be high in raw cornstarch (have a value of 1) or low in cornstarch (have a value of 0); let's call this feature `x`. To test the researcher’s hypothesis, say I build a linear regression model with `x` as a covariate and the coefficient associated with raw cornstarch is 2.76 with a standard error of 0.78. How can I compute if there is evidence to reject the researcher’s claim?
And how can I defend this analysis with someone who has no knowledge of linear models?

Comment: could you indicate alpha level for testing?

Comment: t-estimate = 2.75 × 0.78 = 2.2 approximate ly. compare it with test-statistic.